# My FOR loop is hitting each file twice

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, for-loop, iteration

I am uploading files to a shared file system. So far all is well and on my last step of uploading a file, is to add the fileName to an unordered list.

My problem is that I noticed that it is taking each file and running it through the loop twice.  I cannot attach a file because of security issues(most upload sites are blocked on our system) But I will put the result I get in a block quote.

I have also attached my code.

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim uploads As HttpFileCollection
    uploads = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files

    For i As Integer = 0 To (uploads.Count - 1)

        If (uploads(i).ContentLength > 0) Then
            Dim c As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploads(i).FileName)
            Dim fileSize As Integer = uploads(i).ContentLength

            If fileSize > 1048576 Then
                Span1.InnerHtml = "This file exceeds the allowed file size (1 MB). Please resize the file or select another file."
                BulletedList.Items.Add("The File " & ControlChars.Quote & c & ControlChars.Quote & " -  was larger than (1 mb). Please resize the file or select another file. ")
            ElseIf fileSize < 5 Then
                Span1.InnerHtml = "This file does not contain enough data. Please upload a bigger file."
                BulletedList.Items.Add("The File " & ControlChars.Quote & c & ControlChars.Quote & " does not contain enough data. Please upload a bigger file. ")
            Else
                Try
                    uploads(i).SaveAs("C:\filePath\" + c)
                    BulletedList.Items.Add("The File " & ControlChars.Quote & c & ControlChars.Quote & " was Uploaded Sucessfully.")
                    Span1.InnerHtml = "File Uploaded Sucessfully."
                Catch Exp As Exception
                    Span1.InnerHtml = "Some Error occured."
                End Try
            End If
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
   End Class
```

My output for a successful file:

> File Uploaded Sucessfully.
>
> - The File "normal - Copy (2).txt" was Uploaded Sucessfully.
> - The File "normal - Copy (2).txt" was Uploaded Sucessfully.

Again I cannot see why it is running through the loop twice. Is there a logical error I do not see?

Comment: Is it possible that the click event is being fired twice?  I've seen this happen in ASP.NET (C#) before, but that was a long time ago and I forgot what the cause was.

Comment: Hmm let me google and see what I find. Good thinking.

Comment: Have you debugged to see what uploads.Count is when it enters the loop?

Comment: 'Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click' Was the original. I had to remove 'Handles btnSubmit.Click' from the line. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: wich means you're calling manually the `btnSubmit_Click` method somewhere else?

Comment: Yeah, I had it as an OnClick event on the client side

Answer (score 1):

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
```

In the original string. That `Handles btnSubmit.Click` is causing the event to fire twice. Simple change it to:

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
```

Special Thanks to Tim